# Django JSON Serialization with Mixed Django models and a Dictionary

Tags: python, django, json, serialization

I can't seem to find a good way to serialize both Django Models and Python dictionaries together, its pretty common for me to return a json response that looks like

```
{
  "modified":updated_object,
  "success":true
  ... some additional data...
}
```

Its simple enough to use either simplejson to serialize a dict or Django's serializers.serialize to serialize a model but when I mix them together I get errors.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can't you just convert the model instance to a dict, join the other dict and then serialize?

```
from django.forms import model_to_dict

dict = model_to_dict(instance)
dict.update(dict2)

... Then serialize here ...
```

Don't know about being "better"... :-)

Comment: Source code for model_to_dict can be found at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this (where `products` is queryset):

```
response = {}
products_list = list(products.values('id', 'name', 'description'))
response['products'] = products_list
response['more_data'] = 'more, more, more, things'

json_data = json.dumps(response)
```

Using this method you can select only fields you want (make json, and database query smaller).