# Django - Serializing model with additional data

Tags: django

I am trying to serialize some model data along with some extra information like so:

```
data = {
        'model_data': serializers.serialize('json', SomeModel._default_manager.all(), fields=('name','last_updated')),
        'urls': {
            'updateURL':'http://www.bbc.co.uk',
        },
    }   
    json = simplejson.dumps(data)
```

It seams my 'model_data' object is being serialized twice as it seems to be returned as a string and not a valid json object:

```
Object
model_data: "[{"pk": 1, "model": "models.SomeModel", "fields": {"last_updated": null, "name": "Name test"}}]"
urls: Object
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe try not serializing the model first?

Comment: Returns a "is not JSON serializable" error.

Comment: If all else fails, you could put the model data into a dict.

Comment: duplicated? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959375/django-json-serialization-with-mixed-django-models-and-a-dictionary/17973616#17973616

Answer (score 0):

How about having the value of the model_data field be handled again by another JSON processor? I think it will be the same, since the JSON processor always expects a string that is always in the correct format.