# Python Serialization (to JSON) issue

Tags: python, json, serialization

I'm a bit of a newbie in Python, so go easy on me.  I'm writing an AJAX handler in Django.  Everything's been pretty straight-forward on this until now.  I've been banging my head against this bit for the better part of a day.  I'd like to return a JSON string that contains a dict that contains a queryset:

```
#
# models.py
#

class Project(models.Model):
  unique_name  = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
  title        = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  description  = models.TextField('project description', blank=True)
  project_date = models.DateField('Project completion date')
  published    = models.BooleanField()

class ProjectImage(models.Model):
  project      = models.ForeignKey('Project', related_name='images')
  image        = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
  title        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  sort_metric  = models.IntegerField()


#
# views.py
#
...
projects = Project.Project.objects.filter(published=True)
...
response_dict({
  'success' : True,
  'maxGroups' : 5, # the result of some analysis on the projects queryset
  'projects' : projects
});

# This one works if I remove 'projects' from the dict
# response = json.dumps( response_dict )

# This one works only on projects
# response = serializers.serialize( 'json', response_dict, relations=('images') )

return HttpResponse( response, mimetype='application/javascript' )
```

I've commented out the two serialization lines, because:

1. The first one seems to only work with 'simple' dicts and since projects is included in my dict, it fails with `[<Project: Project object>] is not JSON serializable`
2. The second one seems to only work with querysets/models and since the 'outer' part of my dict is non-model, it complains that `'str' object has no attribute '_meta'`.  Note that I am using the wadofstuff serializer with the understanding that it would resolve the OneToMany relationship as defined in my model.  But even when I get this working by only serializing `projects`, I do not have any of my ProjectImages in the output.

QUESTION 1: What is the best way to serialize the whole `response_dict`?  Surely, I'm not the first person to want to do this, right?

QUESTION 2: Why am I unable to get the ManyToOne relationship to work?

Many thanks for your help.

UPDATE: Just found this one: [Django JSON Serialization with Mixed Django models and a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959375/django-json-serialization-with-mixed-django-models-and-a-dictionary) and it looked promising, but I get `'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_meta'` =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize a python object like that. There is a section in the django documentation on what to do.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2

Here is the key part to look at:

```
json_serializer.serialize(queryset, ensure_ascii=False, stream=response)
```

Comment: which question does this pertain to?  No. 1 or no. 2?  I think what you're suggesting only allows me to serialize the queryset–I can already do this as noted above, however, I cannot seem to include non-Queryset information in the serialized result.

Comment: It pertains to Question #1, if you serialize the projects you should be able to serialize the entire response dict.

Comment: Better late than never =)